# How to clear an object 30 minutes (long running)?

Tags: javascript

I am making a small javascript text RPG, and I want to clear some values every 30 minutes.  These are just logs for my purpose but unfortunately I need them right now for debugging.

For example, I have a `gameLog = {}` to which I am adding some keys for tracking from some of my functions as they get executed.  I want to just clear this every 30 minutes, but I need it to be long-running.  What is the best way to do that?  Thanks

Comment: Probably *setTimeout* and delete all the properties, or set them to *null*? What have you tried?

Comment: I did a set timeout, but that will happen only once.  I can do setInterval, but is there a better way to do this or that should work?

Comment: Each time you call setTimeout, you work out if you want to call it again, then have it call itself in another 30 minutes. I think that's preferable to using *setInterval*.

Comment: I guess instead of clearing every 30 minutes, it's better to set a maximum size and then to clear some old entries whenever you hit that limit.

Answer (score 1):

```
// initialize gameLog as global variable
gameLog = {};

function gameLogClear(){
  gameLog = {};
}

// setup repeating job
gameLogClearTimer = setInterval(gameLogClear, 30 * 60 * 1000);

// timer can be removed with:
// clearInterval(gameLogClearTimer);
```

References:

- [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)
- [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

Comment: `gameLog = {}` doesn't "clear" the old one, it creates a new object so the old one may hang around…

Comment: @RobG Technically, yes, if you happen to have another reference to the old object, it will hang around. It would be more accurate to label the relevant items as "discard".

Answer (score 0):

if you have a *gameLog* object, then you can use *setTimeout* to delete all its properties every 30 minutes and, if you want to keep going, call *setTimeout* again for another 30 minutes, and so on.

```js
var keepGoing = true;
var gameLog = Object.create(null);
gameLog.someProperty = 'foo'; // some initial property

var clearLog = (function() {
  var lag;
  return function (delay) {
    lag = lag || delay || 1.8e6; // default is 30 minutes
    Object.keys(gameLog).forEach(function(key) {
      delete gameLog[key];
    });
    if (keepGoing) {
      setTimeout(clearLog, lag)
    }
    console.log('log cleared... ' + JSON.stringify(gameLog));
  };
}());

clearLog(1000);  // call every second for example
```

At any time, setting *keepGoing* to false means clearLog will stop running after the next *setTimeout* runs. You could also remember the value returned by *setTimeout* and cancel that too.

I'd probably implement *gameLog* as an object with non-enumerable methods (using [*defineProperty*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.defineproperty)) for start, write, clear, and stop where stop clears it and also stops the setTimeout.